# Javascript: debugging on mobile

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs

I've created a simple app using requirejs, angularjs and ui-grid.  All it does is to get some data from an excel file and show it on the grid.

It works nicely when I view it on my desktop, but on mobile (Samsung Galaxy S3) it gives an error (shows the {{myBoundVar}} as if angualr app has not started).  On Nexus 4, it shows the site, but with an empty grid (although I can see it has taken the data, since I see the grid's headers which are taken from the excel).

I can't seem to debug it, since using remote debugging shows the site correctly (just like it shows it correctly on desktop).

Is there a way to debug directly on mobile (e.g. just see the JS errors)?

Comment: you can use adb console. That'll show you all the debug/error/info messages. However, you must filter them to have messages specific to your app only.

Comment: Try this tool for debugging [Vorlon](http://vorlonjs.com/)

Comment: Mateen - one amazing tool! If it would have been an anwer, I would have given it 2 votes up...

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [Remote Debugging on Android with Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging) which allows you to open a live Chrome DevTools window for your website on your android from your Chrome Desktop isntallation as long as you are running Android KitKat or above.

Simply enable developer options on your device, connect it's USB to your computer and visit **chrome://inspect** in your Chrome browser. More detailed instructions are at https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. As I've mentioned, I've already tried that. It's not showing any errors while remotely debugging, but on the mobile device it does have errors.